# The ultimate .NET file and directory utility library?

Tags: c#, file, directory

I find myself writing file and directory utility functions all the time, and I was wondering if there is good file and directory library that already implements a more extensive set than available by default in System.IO. The kind of functions I'm looking for is things like:

```
public static void GetTemporaryDirectory() 
{ 
   string tempDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName()); 
   Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDirectory); 
   return tempDirectory; 
}

public static void CreateEmptyFile(string filename) 
{ 
    File.Create(filename).Dispose(); 
} 

public static void CreateEmptyFile(string path, string filename) 
{ 
    File.Create(Path.Combine(path, filename)).Dispose(); 
} 

public static void CreateDirectory(string path)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}

public static void CreateDirectory(string path, string childpath)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, childpath));
}
```

Comment: Well, your last two methods are trivial wrappers around `Directory.CreateDirectory`.  The middle two I can't see any obvious use for.  The first one *might* be useful, but given that it's 3 lines of code, I don't think we need a library for it. I don't really understand; you're looking for a library that basically implements every possible permutation of file system operations, as opposed to providing a manageable number of useful and easily-composable ones?

Comment: most of this functionality is already in the base .net libaries.

Comment: My first function actually contains a bug:-) Should return a string...

It looks trivial, but it isn't I think. For example a line like File.Create(filename).Dispose();  is not as clear as CreateEmptyFile(filename). Its about the intention, be more descriptive of what you do. The examples may be oversimplistic, but there are many other common cases that could have more descriptive names, even if a function is just a few lines long.

Comment: I remembered I once stumbled accross a great file utility library on codeplex, and I thought I must remember this. I didn't. And I searched for it, and can't find it anymore:-(

Comment: @Serge: My main point was that libraries are intended to deliver *complex* functionality so you don't have to implement it yourself. A library full of these one-liners wouldn't be all that valuable; if I really need a dedicated method to create an empty file, I can write one.

Comment: Sample of code I'm now using this in: [TestInitialize] public void Initialize() { _productDirectory = GetTemporaryDirectory(); CreateEmptyFile(_productDirectory, "ProductRootIndicator.txt"); CreateDirectory(_productDirectory, @"srclib\MySolution"); CreateDirectory(_productDirectory, @"src\ProductDependency\MySolution"); CreateDirectory(_productDirectory, @"MySolution"); }


Hmmm.... no formatting...

Comment: @Aaronaught: you might be right, maybe this is more the kind of things I should write myself in my custom library because it is too specific for my case.

Comment: A good library would let you write a line in the middle of a file without handling the totally reordering of all lines in the file, would let you search for key/value-pairs in an ini-file or xml-file and so on. The Library would know about xml and/or ini (and a lot of other) files and let you just write ChangeValueOfXMLKey(filename,xmlkey,newvalue) and so on. 

So can se a really good use of such kind of librarys. Not just a library that handles io, because.. well we allready have that libraray allready.

So I also want to see more of those. With many new useful methods.

Comment: I agree while it may seem trivial I've found I hate having those 2-3 lines of C# code in hundreds of spots in my applications.  I would rather have a 1 liner that handles it for me.  If you need something very specific for your use just roll your own.  I've written many many Utility classes just like that.

Comment: @Serge: you asked for a "C#" library. Why do you care if it's written in C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although I agree completely with the comments made above, perhaps these libraries might be of interest:

- **[NDepend.Path](https://github.com/psmacchia/NDepend.Path)** (FileDirectoryPath)
- [FluentPath](http://fluentpath.codeplex.com/)
- [Extension Methods](http://dnpextensions.codeplex.com/)
- [Alpha FS](http://alphafs.codeplex.com)

Updated post with FileDirectoryPath link, which looks to be an exact match for OPs request.

Comment: The extension methods certainly look interesting